# Xamarin Cross-Platform Zipcode?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, reverse-geocoding

Right now I'm using [Xamarin.Essentials.Geolocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.geolocation.getlocationasync?view=xamarin-essentials-android). It's an excellent cross-platform tool that allows me to get longitude and latitude from user location. **However, I'm interested in zip code.**

I know in iOS and Android there are separate ways to get user zip code. Is there anything cross-platform?

Comment: XF Maps already has a built in function for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.maps.geocoder.getaddressesforpositionasync?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Maps_Geocoder_GetAddressesForPositionAsync_Xamarin_Forms_Maps_Position_

Comment: @Jason thanks so much!